# Two topologies that have similar subbasis elements

Tags: general-topology

We know that two topologies are equivalent if they have similar basis elements, but does it hold for subbasis elements too? My guess is: Let $\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{T'}$ be two topologies generated by two subbasis $\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{S'}$ respectively. Let $U \in \mathcal{T}$,so $U$ is union of finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal{S}$, which are also elements of $\mathcal{S'}$, which implies $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T'}$, and similarly the other direction as well, so $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T'}$?

Comment: Yes, the topology generated by a subbasis is uniquely determined.